# Converting attribute to caption

Tags: jquery, string, attributes, append, each

I'm using the following code to grab the title attribute from each image I have in my list:

```
$("ul#images li img").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("title");
});
```

How can I then use this attribute as a caption for each image? Do I first need to somehow convert it to a string and then append it to the list item?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of caption? Just text below the image?

Comment: Ideally I will position it absolutely on top of the image, as text taken from the title attribute. At this point I just need it to display in the HTML, I'm pretty sure I can sort it out once it's there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need some CSS and a modification to your javascript. But basically you grab the attr value and append it to where you like.

Using your example:

http://jsbin.com/irabiv/1/edit

```
$("ul#images li img").each(function(index) {
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="caption">'+$(this).attr("title")+'</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are always strings, and the `title` property is also a string so you just have to append it.

```
$("ul#images li img").each(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').append('<br>' + this.title);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/susHP/2/)

Now if you're looking for a more semantic HTML5 solution, I'd suggest using `figure` and `figcaption` elements:

```
$("ul#images li img").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<figure/>').after($('<figcaption>', {text: this.title}));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/susHP/3/)